# Can entries in QNAP (rsnap) hosts file be commented out?

Tags: rsnapshot, qnap

We're using `QNAP rsnap` for our Linux servers backup.
`rsnap` uses the `.../bin/hosts` file to list the machines on which the backup is to run.

*Is there a way to comment out some machines?*
It seems that the '`#`' is not recognised as a comment indicator, e.g. if I have the following hosts file:

```
host1 host2 #host3 host4 host4
```

then the backup will run on `host1, host2, host4, host4,` and the non-existent `#host3`.